# Apply Visual Studio Quick Action on multiple entries

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and have some warnings in my code. For instance:

[image: warning list]

I could apply one at a time but I would like to use the recommended quick action for all of them.
How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know for quick action for all, but for that warning, you can maybe use RegEx : search `(throw new ArgumentNullException\()("(.+?)")` and replace by `$1nameof($3)` [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28throw+new+ArgumentNullException%5c%28%29%28%22%28.%2b%3f%29%22%29&i=throw+new+ArgumentNullException%28%22foo%22%2c+%22bar%22%29&r=%241nameof%28%243%29)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A code fix is available for this rule in Visual Studio. To use it, position the cursor on the string literal and press `Ctrl+. (period)`. Choose Use nameof to express symbol names from the list of options that's presented.

[image]

The thing to note is use the **Fix all occurrences in** whatever option you want.

- Document - will replace it in the current file
- Project - will replace all string literals in current project
- Solution - will replace all string literals in entire solution

Comment: I never really noticed that "Fix all occurences" function. Great!

Comment: Thanks @Cid i hope juergen d rewards me

Comment: VS 2022 doesn't even write anymore the `Fix all occurences` label. Users have to guess what it means... Thanks for this answer, I never knew we can fix them all at once